# Setting selected item in angular md-select with multiple option

Tags: angularjs, sails.js, angular-material, md-select

Setting selected item in angular md-select with multiple option

```
<md-select multiple ng-model="Reg.roles" placeholder="Please select roles" required>
    <md-option ng-repeat="role in roles" value="{{role.value}}" ng-selected="{{ role.value === '<%= data.roles %>' ? 'true' : 'false' }}">{{ role.name }}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

> in my controller

```
 $scope.roles = [{
        "name": "Account Admin",
        "value": "account_admin"
    }, {
        "name": "Developer",
        "value": "developer"
    },


    {
        "name": "Analyst",
        "value": "analyst"
    }
];
```

> in view

**data.roles** contains value:

```
['account_admin', 'developer']
```

I need the item corresponding to **role.value** should be in selected state.

Refer below image [image: current ui showing]

Comment: use ng options some times options does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution, in my controller i wrote this:

```
var current_roles       = '<%=data.roles%>'; // current value from db as array

$scope.Reg.roles = []; //initialize array

angular.forEach($scope.roles, function(val1, key1) {
    if(current_roles.indexOf(val1['value']) !== -1) // check if item in current array
    {
        $scope.Reg.roles.push(val1['value']); //setting to select items
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I dunno how valid this is or if this tackles the same problem but another thing that you could do is that in your HTML, pass in role instead of role.value. So it would look something like this:

```
<md-select multiple ng-model="Reg.roles" placeholder="Please select roles" required>
<md-option ng-repeat="role in roles" value="{{role}}" ng-selected="{{ role.value === '<%= data.roles %>' ? 'true' : 'false' }}">{{ role.name }}</md-option>
```

This allows you to work with the entire object in your controller and you can manipulate it as you wish.